# Как работают учетные записи в postgresql?

Tags: linux, kubuntu, postgresql9.6

Поставил postgesql на Ubuntu, создалась учетка postgresql. Вопрос, с нее происходит инициализация кластера? Имеет ли значение пароль от нее? У меня пароли для конекта и это учетки разные, почему? Если лень обьяснять, скиньте ресурс, плис, буду благодарен, не могу понять это...